# Usage de clair dans "voir plus clair" au lieu de "voir plus clairement"

Tags: usage, adjectifs, adverbes

Dans un e-mail j'ai lu :

> Je vous remercie pour votre retour, cela m'aide à y voir plus clair.

Pourquoi clair et pas clairement ?
L’adjectif clair a-t-il un emploi adverbial ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oui, *clair* peut être un adverbe. Il n'est pas interchangeable avec *clairement* : il n'est pas forcément utilisable dans les mêmes contextes et n'a pas forcément le même sens. L'adverbe *clairement* signifie en général « d'une manière compréhensible » ou « d'une manière évidente », et son sens est à peu près indépendant du verbe. En revanch la plupart des usages de *clair* comme adverbe sont de la forme « [verbe] + *clair* » avec des sens plus ou moins idiomatiques, dans lesquels *clair* garde souvent un sens un peu plus proche de l'adjectif.

Par exemple, « voir clair » (qui ne prend pas de complément) peut signifier au sens propre « voir distinctement » (« je ne vois pas clair parce que mes lunettes sont sales ») ou au sens figuré « comprendre ce qui se passe » (comme dans la phrase de la question). On peut aussi dire « voir clairement », mais c'est plus rare ; ça a (quasiment ?) le même sens propre, mais au un sens figuré l'usage est un peu différent. On peut dire « je vois plus clairement ce qui se passe », ça a le même sens que « j'y vois plus clair », mais on ne dirait pas « je vois plus clairement » ou « j'y vois plus clairement » dans ce sens. On peut par contre utiliser *clairement* lorsque *voir* a un sens d'observation, mais au figuré : « avec les dernières révélations dans la presse, qui ont permis d'y voir plus clair sur les agissements des ministres, on voit clairement que le gouvernement avait menti ».

Le [*Trésor de la langue française*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/clair) cite plusieurs cas d'emploi de *clair* comme adverbe (chercher « adv. »). Par exemple « peindre clair » signifie faire un tableau qui représente beaucoup de lumière, alors que « peindre (quelque chose) clairement » signifie que l'on comprend facilement ce que le tableau représente. On peut dire « il fait clair » pour dire qu'il y a beaucoup de lumière (ou au contraire « il fait sombre »), alors qu'on ne peut pas utiliser *clairement* ou *sombrement* comme ça.